# How to make two rows out of one

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a rather complex and time consuming query which returns a result set with two columns like this:

```
 | ID1 | ID2
   1     10
   2     11
   3     15
```

I want to have those results in one column:

```
| ID
  1
  10
  2
  11
  3
  15
```

Is this possible in (oracle) sql?

The (simplified) query looks like this:

```
SELECT adr.nad_nkt_id id1, firmenadr.nad_nkt_id id2 FROM nav_adressen adr,
      nav_kontakte kontakt, nav_kontakte firma, nav_adressen firmenadr WHERE 
        kontakt.nkt_id = adr.nad_nkt_id AND
        firma.nkt_id (+)= kontakt.nkt_nkt_id AND
        firmenadr.nad_id (+)= firma.nkt_id AND
        (firmenadr.nad_strasse like '%needle%' OR
         adr.nad_strasse like '%needle%');
```

Comment: Instead of redoing things in database, cant you consider storing the data in an array/list in your client code?

Comment: as per your query id1 and id2 have same value, Is it correct ?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar This query is only part of a bigger query, which uses the id for further computation.

Comment: @PragneshKhalas they are both integer but one row can hold two different values (or one value and null right).

Comment: But you get filed for id and id2 is same “adr.nad_nkt_id id1, adr.nad_nkt_id id2” in your query

Comment: Good point @PragneshKhalas  This query could likely be optimized.

Comment: @PragneshKhalas Whoops sry, this is just a mistake.. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with source as (
SELECT adr.nad_nkt_id id1, firmenadr.nad_nkt_id id2 FROM nav_adressen adr,
  nav_kontakte kontakt, nav_kontakte firma, nav_adressen firmenadr WHERE 
    kontakt.nkt_id = adr.nad_nkt_id AND
    firma.nkt_id (+)= kontakt.nkt_nkt_id AND
    firmenadr.nad_id (+)= firma.nkt_id AND
    (firmenadr.nad_strasse like '%needle%' OR
     adr.nad_strasse like '%needle%')
)
select decode(x.l, 1, a.id1, 2, a.id2) as id
  from source a
 cross join (select level as l from dual connect by level <=2) x
```

In this case you do not need to scan result set twice. It might be faster than union method.

Comment: Thanks! This approach looks interesting, but it does not execute. There is a typo in "...needle%');", i guess the ';' has to be removed, but even with the ';' removed it does not work as intended..

Comment: It was a bug in my sql tool, i am going to check it tomorrow in php, thanks again.

Comment: Yes, sorry - it was copy/paste error. I can't reproduce your query so just cut and pasted. Let me remove this semicolon.

Comment: btw, WITH clause is optional - you can re-write it as select ... from (select...)

Answer (score 2):

You're after a `UNION`:

```
SELECT ID1
FROM YourTable
UNION 
SELECT ID2
FROM YourTable
```

`UNION` will return distinct items, `UNION  ALL` will return all items (and is therefore faster).

Given the amount of filtering/joining you're doing, it makes sense to do the filtering first into a temp table then run the `UNION`.

Comment: This is a valid solution but wouldn't it take way too much time to execute the query twice?

Comment: @NickRussler If you're doing extensive filtering then you may benefit from filtering the full set before running the `UNION`, but otherwise no, I don't think there's a better method.

Answer (score 2):

```
select ID1 as ID from TableA
union
select ID2 as ID from TableA
```